# ¿Cómo se llama alguien que está estudiando un grado?

Tags: vocabulario-técnico

Alguien que ha terminado un grado universitario puede ser *graduado*, *licenciado*, *doctorado*, etc.
Alguien que ha terminado bachillerato se denomina *Bachiller*. Pero, ¿cómo se le llama a alguien que está cursando un grado universitario?
Supongo que habrá otra palabra además de *estudiante*

Comment: En algunos casos tal vez bastaría con decir "universitario", que es una palabra general que incluye a los alumnos.

Comment: @Rodrigo:"Universitario" según el DLE es:  4. m. y f. **Profesor, graduado** o estudiante de universidad.

Comment: @Leonardo - Sí, pero en la práctica, en México por lo menos, se hace la distinción entre *profesor universitario*, *licenciado* (= graduado) y *universitario* (= estudiante).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para alguien cursando su doctorado, existen por lo menos los siguientes términos:

- <sup>alumno/a</sup>/<sub>estudiante</sub> de doctorado
- <sup>alumno/a</sup>/<sub>estudiante</sub> doctoral
- (<sup>alumno/a</sup>/<sub>estudiante</sub>) doctorante
- doctorando

En el caso del título de *grado*, que sepa yo, no hay una forma adjetival análoga a *doctoral* (sería *gradual*, que obviamente existe, pero con significados muy distintos).  No obstante, no sería problema formar las otras:

- <sup>alumno/a</sup>/<sub>estudiante</sub> de grado
- (<sup>alumno/a</sup>/<sub>estudiante</sub>) graduante
- graduando

No recomendaría *graduante* porque tiende a usarse ya para representar la gente que, en la ceremonia de graduación, van a recibir aquel día su título.  Igualmente, la forma análoga, *doctorante* parecer disfrutar de uso solo en Méjico (aunque el francés ha optado por la misma forma y es España el país que suele aprovechar de las construcciones francesas).  *Graduando* está recogido ya en el DRAE, pero personalmente nunca lo he escuchado en persona.

Lo más normal es simplemente **alumno de grado**.